# iText: Cell Content Phrase not present

Tags: itext

When I invoke the:

```
public class App 
{
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    try {

        TemplateGenerator tg = new TemplateGenerator();
        tg.generateTemplateFile();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

and

```
public class TemplateGenerator {

    Font cellTitle=null;
public void generateTemplateFile() throws IOException, DocumentException {

        File file = new File(Properties.TEMPLATE_FILE);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        this.createPdf(Properties.TEMPLATE_FILE);

}

private void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));


    document.setPageSize(this.setupPageSize(Properties.WIDTH_MM,
                                            Properties.HEIGHT_MM));
    document.setMargins(2, 2, 2, 2);

    document.open();

        document.add(buildFrames());

    document.close();
}

private Rectangle setupPageSize(Float width, Float height){
    return new Rectangle(   Utilities.millimetersToPoints(width),
                            Utilities.millimetersToPoints(height));
}

private void setupFonts() throws IOException, DocumentException {
    cellTitle = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 13, Font.NORMAL, GrayColor.GRAYBLACK);

}

private PdfPTable buildFrames(){
    PdfPTable table;
    table = null;
    try{
        Font fontH1 = new Font(Font.FontFamily.COURIER, 16, Font.NORMAL);

        table = new PdfPTable(1);

        table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("aaa",fontH1)));


    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return table;
}
```

}

I get the cell printed but it is **empty** ie. no "aaa" tekst in it. No matter what the cell text is not appearing. I wonder what is wrong no errors. I got the file stored in src/main/resources with 664 access rights. What is wrong?

Comment: what happens without the font ? You might need to init or change its  color, with the *setColor* method.

Comment: Actually even if i run the official (without font) example: [http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables/101-very-simple-table#1488-simpletable.java] I got simply just table 6x2 without the "hi phrase". I use the 5.4.5 iText

Comment: The official example runs fine and works perfectly. I've just tested it. What is claimed in this question either isn't true, or there is something else at play that isn't being explained in the question.

Comment: *I got the file stored in src/main/resources* - you mean your java code? Or the result pdf? Usually neither makes sense.

Comment: Actually as it has occured it is a problem with Evince ver 3.10 not the iText